# how can I use Api for downloading pictures in all of the view controllers in page view controller?

Tags: ios, json, api, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller in my app and this page view controller has 4 view controller - so I have Image View in all of these page View controller and I want to use Json Api to download images in these pages

Here is my Code But I copied this code in all of my view controllers class so I just write one of them here

```
func refreshingphoto1() {

    let firstImageURL = URL(string: "http://img.autobytel.com/car-reviews/autobytel/11694-good-looking-sports-cars/2016-Ford-Mustang-GT-burnout-red-tire-smoke.jpg")!

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    // Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.


    let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: firstImageURL) { (data, response, error) in
        // The download has finished.

        if error != nil {
            print("Error downloading picture")
            self.firstImageJson.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
        } else {

            // No errors found.
            // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {

                print("Downloaded picture with response code")

                if let imageData = data {

                    // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.firstImageJson.image = image
                    // Do something with your image.

                } else {


                    print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                    self.firstImageJson.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")

                }
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                self.firstImageJson.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
            }
        }
    }
    downloadPicTask.resume()
}
}
```

**This Will work But Not Completely true **

and here is the picture of my story Board

[as you see in the picture I have Page VC2 that is page view controller and four view controllers that connected to the page VC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAOAN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have multiple VC has little to do with the task of downloading images.

However, apart for a lack of abstraction, you are on the right track : using `URLSession` and `URLSessionTask` is the right way to do by using Apple APIs.

You may be interested in the following, though ; to abstract things a lot of developer use this third-party library named [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and specifically for your case [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

For example with AlamofireImage you'd just have to do

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder")!

imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Comment: does it looking for dictionary? or not?